# While loop for TCPDF

Tags: php

I have problem to loop the data in TCPDF..The output should be display like this

**Output** :

```
 Chair x 3 
 Table x 5 
 LCD  X 2
```

but output now just show : `Chair x 3`

It only display the first record. Can anyone explain
how to loop the data based on output above?

```
$result_1=mysql_query($query_1);
   while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result_1)){
     $item = $row1['item'];
     $qty = $row1['SUM(qty)'];            
     $data = $item.' x '.$qty;    
     $tbl.='<td align="center">'.$data.'</td>';       
     $data='';
   }
$tbl.='</tr>';
}
```

[This picture output I get based on coding above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRKwU.png)

Comment: your overwriting your string in the loop

Comment: i'm sorry, i don't understand what do u mean..can u show example for me?

Comment: im wrong that should work

Comment: yup..supposed to be like that.. T_T

Comment: Is your mysql query returning all the data you expect?

Comment: yes..when I put  echo in front of  $data = $item.' x '.$qty;  .. echo $data = $item.' x '.$qty;   **output**  :  Chair x 3 Table x 5 LCD x 2 TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is answer for my question. I just add  **$data.**  at 
 $data =  $item.' x '.$qty; 
 and my problem has been solved.

```
    $result_1=mysql_query($query_1);
    while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result_1)){

        $item = $row1['item'];
        $qty = $row1['SUM(qty)'];

    $data =  $data.$item.' x '.$qty.'<br>';  

    }
   $tbl.='<td align="center">'.$data.'</td>';
   $data='';
$tbl.='</tr>';
 }
```